# Dropbox on a dual-boot machine

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, ext4, dropbox

I have a dual boot laptop- Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10, both located on same HD, different partitions, and a third one, meant to be for common use.

To avoid putting my Dropbox folder on each OS, I wish to install it on that 3rd partition. I though that "FAT32" will fit for that job, but when I installed Dropbox on Windows side, it asked for "NTFS" (so it was changed from "FAT32" to "NTFS") and when I switch to Ubuntu, Dropbox asked for "Ext4".

Can this situation be solved ?

Comment: Sharing the Dropbox folder between the OSes, as others have pointed out, is quite risky and error-prone.

You can consider going with an external NAS that supports Dropbox (for example, Synology) if you're using your laptop mostly in a single location, and then mount the drive on both OSes from a local network location. I'm using this solution for years now and I'm happy with it.

Comment: @synweap15 It was one of my first solutions in mind, but WD double bay cloud does not support Dropbox

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Q. Can this situation be solved?**

Nope.

Which probably leads to ...

**Q. Why not?**

The problem comes down to how Dropbox relies on the journaling mechanism of the file system to know when a file has been changed. This reduces the overhead of actively watching (potentially) millions of files, which comes with a high cost.

Linux does not have a mechanism to observe the NTFS journal in a reliable manner, so the Dropbox client cannot use NTFS file systems. Windows has a similar issue in that it does not have a reliable means of reading the Ext4 journal. FAT-based file systems do not use journaling at all, which is why Dropbox stopped supporting those file systems [several years ago](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Write-to-a-Dropbox-folder-on-NTFS-from-linux/m-p/214848#M25994).

Answer (score 10):

This used to work, but as the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403298/301745) says, Dropbox blocks file systems they do not want to support. At the time they made this change, I also required dual booting, and moved away from Dropbox.

It is possible to patch away the restriction. You can use it at your own risk, I haven't tested it myself: https://github.com/dark/dropbox-filesystem-fix. Here are [installation instructions](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/patch-dropbox-for-linux-pcs-that-dont-use-ext4/).

You might also try [Maestral](https://maestral.app/about/), which is an alternative client for Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use Dropbox since I work on my C++ on several computers which are on different OS (Mac, Linux and lately Windows). I store my dev github libraries.

Dropbox was the only with cross platform agent. Google Drive is not suitable on Linux. Can you recommend ?

Comment: @guyd `git clone` ?

Comment: For source code, it is really worth it to learn git, even if you only use very basic commands in the beginning. For other documents, I am happy with NextCloud/OwnCloud which has native apps for Win, Linux, Mac. You can host your own server, but there are also multiple commerical services.

Comment: I use git, but I need that "cloud-like" update between commits since sometime I work on Mac and check other feature on Linux practically same time. Any cloud that update almost simultaneously is what I need for my way of working.

Comment: @guyd - It may be a good idea to use git commit instead of "cloud like update", because it is much easier to recover mistakenly deleted code that way. You can execute `git add . && git commit -m "whatever" && git push origin main` with a single, short command (just create an executable in `~/.local/bin`). Moreover, if you have [`github-cli`](https://cli.github.com/) installed, you will not even need to enter your password to push your code to GitHub.

Comment: @guyd What you are saying makes *zero* sense... There are plenty of cloud free services for git such as github or bitbucket. You should really just `git commit` and `git push` and then `git pull` on the other OS. Using Dropbox in place of git push&pull is, simply put, dumb and wont work.

Comment: If you really need "cloud-like update", I'm sure every operating system you need to use has a mechanism to watch a directory for changes. You save a file, the OS detects a change in the contents of the watched directory, and runs a `git commit && git push` for you. You could also have a similar thing pulling from the github commit every 5 minutes, but you really don't want that (merge conflicts)!